# Passing powershell values to command line tools

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace the powershell values in the command line tool but couldn't figure it out.

```
$a = "C:\Test\TestApp.exe"
$args = "arg1 arg2 arg3"


& schtasks /create /SC ONLOGON /TN "Test Task" /tr "'$a' $args" /F

//expected - schtasks /create /SC ONLOGON /TN "Test Task" /tr "'C:\Test\TestApp.exe' arg1 arg2 arg3" /F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$args`  with a different var like `$MyArgs`

See this excerpt from `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`

```
$Args
   Contains an array of the undeclared parameters and/or parameter
   values that are passed to a function, script, or script block.
   When you create a function, you can declare the parameters by using the
   param keyword or by adding a comma-separated list of parameters in
   parentheses after the function name.

   In an event action, the $Args variable contains objects that represent
   the event arguments of the event that is being processed. This variable
   is populated only within the Action block of an event registration
   command.  The value of this variable can also be found in the SourceArgs
   property of the PSEventArgs object (System.Management.Automation.PSEventArgs)
   that Get-Event returns.
```